# Procedimiento almacenado sql, utilizando como parametros una cadena en JSON.

Tags: mysql

Quiero realizar un procedimiento almacenado en MYSQL, al cual se le pase un texto con estructura JSON, y convertir este texto a JSON en el procedimiento para obtener los datos.

- El JSON no siempre tendrá los mismos campos. Se pretende es guardar solo los datos que lleguen en el JSON, con el fin de hacer inserciones dinámicamenten. Espero eso sea posible hacerlo .

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado mi estimado?

Comment: Estuve revisando esta documentación , sin embargo solo  se hacen inserciones a campos json, pero lo que yo tengo es una tabla normal  en donde guardaré los datos que recibiré en el procedimiento en cadena json como parametro en el procedimiento y dentro del procedimiento tendré que obtener cada dato. lo que no se hacer es como acceder a cada clave y vlaor de un json en un procedimiento almacenado. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html